# how to add dynamic content inside a textarea tag using map method

Tags: reactjs, sockets, socket.io, react-hooks, mern

i am currently working on **chat application with sockets** , when i get different messages i use an **array and then use map** method to display them in simple html tags like **p** etc it worked perfect but inside **text-area** its not working i also tried to set text-area **value** property with map method but only i see is **[object object]** . also how can i automatically  move the scroll bar down when messages there are more messages.

**here is the code**

```
import { Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import { format } from "date-fns";
const Chat = ({ name, message }) => {
  const date = new Date();
  const hour = date.getHours();
  const minute = date.getMinutes();
  const second = date.getSeconds();

  console.log("so bteay", message);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>
        <h3 className="d-inline-block me-3"> Chat log </h3>
        {name && (
          <span className="me-3 d-inline-block">
            <div
              class="spinner-grow spinner-grow-sm text-success"
              style={{ fontSize: "10px" }}
              role="status"
            >
              <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
            </div>
          </span>
        )}
        <small className="text-muted d-block  "> {name}</small>
        <textarea
          cols="70"
          rows="8"
          value={message.map((eachMsg) => {
            return (
              <Fragment>
                {
                  <small className="text-muted d-inline-block">{`${hour}:${minute}:${second}`}</small>
                }
                <p
                  className="d-block shadow p-1 fw-bold rounded text-success"
                  style={{ fontFamily: "cursive" }}
                >
                  {eachMsg}
                </p>
              </Fragment>
            );
          })}
        ></textarea>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

Comment: Just print "eachMsg" before return and see whether it has string or object, Most probably you get an object instead of text

Comment: @SameeraMillavithanachchi  actually i did that and the when i console.log it it logged eachMsg successfully   as text not object !

Comment: You can't render html inside textarea.  so try with the following <React.Fragment>
      <textarea
          cols="70"
          rows="8"
          value={messages.map((eachMsg) => {
            return eachMsg;
          })}
        ></textarea>
    </React.Fragment>

Answer (score 2):

You can only pass 1 child ( text in this case ) to text area. But you are trying to pass an array. If what you meant to do is to have as many as textareas as your array, this is how you should go about it:

```
const texts = ["Hi", "Bye","done"];

<div>
      {texts.map((text) => (
        <textarea>text</textarea>
      ))}
</div>
```

but if you are trying to have 1 textarea with all your texts inside it, first you need to create a long string using `join` method, and then render that string.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't set html code inside textarea, unless you want to show it as a text?